# How to get in JQuery the current day printed out in the HTML by clicking the div defined within the JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a clickable event calendar with JavaScript and responsive modal and struggling with. Any JS specialist who could please help?

Goal/Challenge: I'd like to click the day field in the calendar, display a modal which automatically fills the date field with the correspondent date for that field by retrieving that day number and creating a calendar within the JQuery which displays in the date input the date.

Here the starting code:

```
 var dt = new Date();
        function renderDate() {
            dt.setDate(1); 

            var day = dt.getDay(); 

            var today = new Date();

            var endDate = new Date(
                dt.getFullYear(),
                dt.getMonth() + 1, 
                0
            ).getDate();

            var prevDate = new Date(
                dt.getFullYear(), 
                dt.getMonth(), 
                0
            ).getDate();

            var months = [
                "Januar",
                "Februar",
                "März",
                "April",
                "Mai",
                "Juni",
                "Juli",
                "August",
                "September",
                "Oktober",
                "November",
                "Dezember"
            ]
            document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = months[dt.getMonth()]; 
            document.getElementById("date_str").innerHTML = dt.getFullYear(); 
            var cells = "";

            for (x = day; x > 0; x--) {
                cells += "<div class='month-day'><div class='eachday prev_date'>" + (prevDate - x + 1) + "</div></div>"
            }
```

Here the code starts printing within "div class='month-day nBtn'" for each day of the current month. And the class name nBtn calls in a JQuery a modal in which I would like to pass the current day printed out.

```
            for (i = 1; i <= endDate; i++) { 
                if (i == today.getDate() && dt.getMonth() == today.getMonth()) cells += "<div class='today'>" + i + "</div>"; 
                else 
                    cells += "<div class='month-day nBtn'><div class='eachday'>" + i + "</div></div>";
            }
            document.getElementsByClassName("days")[0].innerHTML = cells; 

        }
        function moveDate(para) {
            if(para == "prev") {
                dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1); 
            } else if(para == 'next') {
                dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + 1); 
            }
            renderDate();
        }
```

JQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $('.nBtn').on('click',function(){
                $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal(); 
            });                     
        });
```

When I try to retrieve the index I get only zero for all fields I click in the calendar in HTML script code. I'd like to get in the JQuery code the number for the day printed out in the field I have clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('.nBtn').on('click',function(){
      var day = $(this).find('.eachday').text();
      $('.myForm #exampleModal').html(day);
      $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal(); 
   });                     
});
```

Comment: Hi Flash :) thank you! To test it I used an alert() function. It returns twice a result. The first it is indeed the value of the clicked day in the calendar, what is good. But when I close the alert box it returns a second alert box with all numbers in the calendar. Does this have anything to do with the fact that the .nBtn class that calls the JQuery code is inside a for loop?

Comment: Are the scripts in loop as well? Shouldn't be returning results twice. Could you show the real live code?